Identifying chief subject
I've come across the following sentence:

The student, as well as the committee members,
is excited.

To my understanding there are two subjects:

the student —singular

the committee members —plural.


And the verb is becomes are.

The student, as well as the committee members,
are excited.

In the following thread
Subject Verb agreement with comma-aside of a different pluralization
the problem is reduced to identifying chief subject.
When a sentence has more than one subject per verb,
those subjects form a compound subject.
TWO SINGULAR: The dog and the cat bother me.
TWO PLURAL: The dogs and the cats bother me.
ONE SINGULAR, ONE PLURAL: The dog and cats bother me.
If plural subjects are joined by “or,” “nor,” or “but,” the verb must only agree with the
subject that is closest to it.
Example: Either Bob or his brother walks to the store.
Neither Bob nor his brothers walk to the store.
Not Bob but his brothers walk to the store
Not Bob but his brother walks to the store
My question is, when two subjects co-exist,
one singular, one plural, what to use singular
or plural verb. Some rules?

This has been dealt with before on this site and its sister site. Have you checked the site  for possible duplicates?

Parentheticals do not affect agreement. The student, who is also one of the committee members, is excited. //  The student, who was selected for this task by the committee members, is excited. // The student, as well as the committee members, is excited. //// But The student and the committee members are excited. [not regarded as a parenthetical, but a compound subject]
